# How do I fill a Pyplot Line plot and change the fill depended on the value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a pd DataFrame which holds a Depth column and a number of other columns for variables at those depth points. Plotting line graphs is fine. What i want to do is plot Depth against category (integer, 1-6) and have the bar or fill change based on category. I also want to be able to sharey=true with adjoining line type subplots.
I have tried with a horizontal bar but depth isn't taken into account as the BarH is just sequential (in this example my depth data only goes to 0.064). [image: This is a BarH adjacent to my Depth/Category plot]

I have also tried plotting Depth/Category trying to span_where but with limited success. I can make it work with randomly generated data but not when I read a csv into my DataFrame.

```
    import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections as collections


data= pd.read_csv (r'/Users/????/Desktop/snippit.csv')
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Depth','SBTno'])
df['Depth']*=-1 #invert depths - below seabed
y=df.SBTno  #This is the bit that seems to casue the errors
x=df.Depth  #Using np genertaed figure works.

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y,color='red')

Z1=1
Z2=2
Z3=3
Z4=4
Z5=5

collection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(
    x, ymin=0, ymax=Z1,where=x >Z1, facecolor='green',alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection(collection)
collection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(
    x, ymin=0, ymax=Z2,where=y >Z2, facecolor='red',alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection(collection)
collection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(
    x, ymin=0, ymax=Z3,where=y >Z3, facecolor='blue',alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection(collection)
collection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(
    x, ymin=0, ymax=Z4,where=y >Z4, facecolor='grey',alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection(collection)
collection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(
    x, ymin=0, ymax=Z5,where=y >Z5, facecolor='purple',alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection(collection)

plt.show()
```

This is a snippet of the data. I am plotting Depth/SBTno (integer, 1-5)

```
Depth,Cone,Friction,SBTno
0,0,0,0
0.001,0.012,0.003,2
0.005,0.02,0.003,2
0.009,0.044,0.003,3
0.013,0.052,0.003,4
0.017,0.071,0.004,5
0.021,0.129,0.004,4
0.025,0.193,0.004,4
0.028,0.265,0.005,3
0.033,0.408,0.005,2
0.036,0.624,0.005,1
0.04,0.898,0.005,4
0.044,1.36,0.005,4
0.048,1.68,0.006,4
0.052,2.047,0.006,3
0.056,2.209,0.006,5
0.06,2.249,0.007,2
0.064,2.217,0.007,2
```

[image: This is my plot so far, i am trying to color scale the right-hand plot]

Above is my plot, I want to color scale the right hand line plot dependant on the category (SBTno) value.
Below is what I am trying to create.

What I am trying to create is this.
[image: Where i want to get to]5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of blind alleys, I have come up with the following code. I have ordered the fills (with no alpha) so they sit on top of each other, effectively masking the underlying fill.  Possibly not elegant, but go the job done.

```
axs[1].fill_betweenx(df['Depth'],0,df['SBTn'], where=(df['SBTn'])>=1,facecolor='red')
axs[1].fill_betweenx(df['Depth'],0,df['SBTn'], where=(df['SBTn'])>=2,facecolor='#dc7633')
axs[1].fill_betweenx(df['Depth'],0,df['SBTn'], where=(df['SBTn'])>=3,facecolor='#5f5b95')
axs[1].fill_betweenx(df['Depth'],0,df['SBTn'], where=(df['SBTn'])>=4,facecolor='#45b39d')
axs[1].fill_betweenx(df['Depth'],0,df['SBTn'], where=(df['SBTn'])>=5,facecolor='#76d7c4')
axs[1].fill_betweenx(df['Depth'],0,df['SBTn'], where=(df['SBTn'])>=6,facecolor='#f0b27a')
axs[1].fill_betweenx(df['Depth'],0,df['SBTn'], where=(df['SBTn'])>=7,facecolor='#e59866')
```

With the following result. The transitions aren't sharp (step-wise or perpendicular to axis) but as they represent soil condition change from one sample to the next, a slope is ok.
    [image: finished (maybe) product.]